# Hero with gradient using ::before not working correctly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to have a hero image page with a gradient using the `::before` selector. The effect is working but there is one issue; it is out position so I want it to fit over the `.hero` div but there are some offset.

I only could get this working using the absolute position which is not the ideal for this.

```
.hero1 {
  background: image-url('noche-en-santo-domingo.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 89vh;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 6vw;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#002f4b,#dc4225);
    opacity: .4; 
  }

  .intro {
      padding: 3rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
   }   
}
```

```
<section id="hero" class="hero1">
   <div class="row intro">
      <div class="small-centered medium-uncentered medium-6 large-7 columns">
         <h1>We are caribbean developers</h1>
         <p><strong>We Help the People make Better Software and we are young people with bilingual skills and professionalism, specializing in various areas of Information Technology (IT)</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-centered medium-uncentered medium-6 large-5 columns">
         <div class="tech-img"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

You can go and test here: http://carey.peopleware.do

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently positioning your `:before` with a value of `12vh`. This will position the element with a value equal to 12% of the window height. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Give your `.hero1` element a position value of `relative` and the `:before` a `top` of `0`:

```
.hero1 {
  ...
  position: relative;
  &::before {
  ...
  top: 0;
}
```

This will position your `:before` relative to the parent `hero1` element and eliminate the offset that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks you it worked. I updated the CSS. **never mind on my previous comment**

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `position: relative;` to .hero1 , because you use absolute positioning on ::before selector. This way you will not have offsets.